# How to get a list of features from FME? Python?

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I would like to get a list of geodatabase feature tables from FME.
Is it possible with Python? Or another transformer?

Comment: Do you specifically need to get this list from FME?  I only ask since it looks like the data is coming from an Esri geodatabase.  Would an ArcCatalog solution be acceptable?

Comment: ArcCatalog is not the final solution for the development. I use a workbench and i would like a list of GDB feature because i would like to export the feature table to an another file.

Comment: I find the solution with Python is here (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/how-to-list-feature-classes-with-active-attribute-domains)

Comment: As long as you have the ESRI stuff installed; ArcPy is just a wrapper to the ArcGIS classes/Methods; if you are wanting to keep this entirely in the FME realm then Mark's answer is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a dynamic reader (ie one with just a single source feature type with the merge filter set). Then expose the fme_feature_type format attribute. This will give you the name of the table being read.

You can run the data through a DuplicateRemover too, removing duplicate values for fme_feature_type, in order to get a list of unique table names.

There is a Schema format that returns the schema of a dataset, but I think it works only with file-based data, and wouldn't work with a File Geodatabase (though it might with a Personal Geodatabase).

Comment: Ok, I saw that but didn't have the time to play with it. Thanks for the suggestion Mark!

Comment: There is a sample of Python with FME ? Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use Python. Just expose the source format attribute called fme_feature_type - that will tell you the name of the table where the feature is from. It doesn't need to be dynamic either - I just suggest that as a way for the workspace to operate on any source dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can list object in any ESRI connection; as long as you have the ArcGIS Server installed on that machine you can use the list object in ArcPy to return a array of feature classes.
You will just want to make sure that is you are dynamically checking a variety of Geodatabases that you have your parameter for your workspace set.

Comment: I use a geodatabase file and fme desktop.I have not ArcGis server on my desktop.

Comment: Hmmm, ok; that is a different place. I am digging through my Workbench and for the life of me am not seeing a place to actually list what is in the Reader.