# Find features that use specific domain in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, domains

I have a geodb file with a set of domains. 
Now, I need to check which are the features with attributes using a specific domain in arccatalog. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can use arcpy to write a tiny script that will find what fields have domains associated with them. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/how-to-list-feature-classes-with-active-attribute-domains

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I'm not sure about your first link which does not mention domains but your second seems very useful.

Comment: @PolyGeo, ah sorry wrong URL pasted...