# Listing Feature Classes of Multiple geodatabase in Multiple Folder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, esri-geodatabase

I'm new in python scripting and try to list polyline feature classes of multiple Geodatabases. The Geodatabases are in many nested folders.For example in folder "A" I have 20 folders and in each folder i have 3 geadatabases. the question is that how can i list the feature classes of the geodatabases using Arcpy. I know simple Python codes to list feature classes in a folder such as :

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = ".././Data/6"
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fclist
```

I surf in this site and found a  Q&A about [How to list feature classes in multiple Geodatabases in a folder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16464/how-to-list-feature-classes-in-multiple-geodatabases-in-a-folder) . It was very useful but only for multi Geodatabases not multi folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) function from ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 allows you to do this.  The following script walks through a workspace, create a list of every polyline, and copies the polylines to an output workspace.

```
import arcpy
import os

in_workspace = r"C:\your\path"
out_workspace = r"C:\your\path2\temp.gdb\fds"

feature_classes = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(in_workspace, datatype="FeatureClass",type="Polyline"):
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print feature_classes

# Loop through the "feature_classes" list and copy featureclasses to out_workspace
for fc in feature_classes:
    name = os.path.basename(fc) # Extract only the FC basename 
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, os.path.join(out_workspace, name))
```

Comment: nice.is there any method without using sp1 ? thnx

Comment: I could not use this function to copy feature classes using arcpy.CopyFeatures_management How can i use this function to copy the list features ?  thnx

Comment: @wetland post edited to address your comment.  I hope this helps.

Comment: it's not working . I just use your edited answer in loop of arcpy.da.Walk

Comment: I just tested the script again--all is well.  What errors are you receiving?

Comment: You may be missing the following from the second for     loop "feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))"

Comment: @Aaron.ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset D:\Il\ken\test.gdb\antalya_Rabour already exists.
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures) . Thnx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8535/discussion-between-aaron-and-wetland)

Answer (score 1):

I created the following function in Python that takes as input a starting folder and populates a global list with all the sub-folder paths. You can then step through this using the **arcpy.ListWorkspaces()**

```
import arcpy
import os

listFolders = []

def GetFolders(root):
    global listFolders
    try:
        l = os.listdir(root)
        for x in l:
            path = root + "\\" + x
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                listFolders.append(path)
                GetFolders(path) # Recursive call here!
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        # An error occurred set list to empty
        listFolders = []
```