# Selecting specific filenames nested within several folders?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, shapefile

I have hundreds of shapefiles that are stored in separate folders, which are nested within several other folders. Among the shapefiles I only need the ones that are named 'POINT*.shp'

How do I get these specific shapefiles so I can then add fields, calculate fields, etc.?

If there is a better option than `os.walk`, please tell. I'm only beginning to learn python, so this is very new to me.

Comment: What version of ArcMap/Python do you have access to?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.1 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 8):

Use os.walk and then loop through the files appending to a list, where the filename starts with 'point' and ends with '.shp'.

```
import os
path = "D:/Files/GIS/Datafiles/"
shp_list = []
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if f.lower().endswith(".shp") and f.lower().startswith("point"):
            print f
            fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            shp_list.append(fullpath)
```

Comment: Maybe less identation at "print" and below? Otherwise, very good. A regex doesn't help in this particular case but might in others.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin. The only issue is that the shapefiles don't necessarily being with "point" -- sometimes it is in the middle of the name, and sometimes at the end. Is there a function that would say something like 'contains("point")'?

Comment: @sgillies: thanks. I edited out the extra indentation.

Comment: @S.S.: yes, just use if f.lower().find("point") <> -1

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59350/how-to-list-feature-classes-of-multiple-geodatabase-in-multiple-folder), but this is only helpful if you have access to ArcMap 10.1 SP1.  If so you could use the [da.walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000) to look for shapefiles.  If you want any feature class with POINT in the name, you could do the following:

```
import arcpy, os, fnmatch
# Set the workspace with user input
arcpy.env.workspace = "Your directory here"
inWorkspace = arcpy.env.workspace
pointList = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(inWorkspace, followlinks=True, datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for filename in filenames:
        # Add any field with "POINT" in the filename when creating list
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, "*POINT*"):
            pointList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

This creates a list (pointList) of complete paths to shapefiles with "POINT" in the name within your specified directory.  Alternatively you could include type="Point" in the arcpy.da.Walk() to search for only POINT feature classes.