# How to export list of feature classes in multi gdb's to a csv file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

Using the codes mentioned here [Listing feature classes in multiple geodatabases in folder using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16464/how-to-list-feature-classes-in-multiple-geodatabases-in-a-folder) i was able to list all the feature_classes in multiple geodatabases within a folder. Problem is i don't know how to save the print results to a csv file. I knew, in theory - i have to create a csv file -> open it -> Append the "Print_results" to that file. Since i don't have any experience in python i don't know how to execute it.

Currently i'm trying with this code

```
import arcpy

dir = r'D:\Test\gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = dir

gdbList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*','FileGDB')

filename = r'D:\Test\FC_List.csv

with open(filename, 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for gdb in gdbList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb               
    datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')     
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()         
    for fc in fcList:
        print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
    for dataset in datasetList:            
        arcpy.env.workspace = dataset  
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()    
        for fc in fcList:
            print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        for each_fs in fcList:
            wr.writerow(each_fs.split(","))
            print (each_fs)
```

I've refered to the code mentioned here https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/163571/Write-a-list-of-personal-geodatabase-fea. Actually, this code is creating the Fc_list.csv file. But only as an empty csv file

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48537/how-to-make-a-gis-inventory

Comment: I believe you need the for loop inside the with statement.

Answer (score 1):

As @dslamb mentioned you need your for loop inside the 'with' statement.

```
import arcpy
import csv

dir = r'D:\Test\gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = dir
gdbList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*','FileGDB')
filename = r'D:\Test\FC_List.csv'

with open(filename, 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for gdb in gdbList:  # right here and beyond
        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for fc in fcList:
            wr.writerow(fc.split(",")) # Get fc outside of dataset
            print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
        for dataset in datasetList:
            arcpy.env.workspace = dataset
            fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
            for fc in fcList:
                print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
            arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
            for each_fs in fcList:
                wr.writerow(each_fs.split(","))
                print (each_fs)
```

Comment: Tried with this code. It is listing the feature_classes in console & creating an empty csv file.

Comment: @saravanaganesh18 what about changing the second to the last line from `wr.writerow(each_fs.split(","))` to `myfile.write(each_fs + '\n')`? I find it strange it is able to print, but not able to write it out to the csv. Both methods have worked for me.

Comment: Still the same. It's printing the feature_classes name and creating the csv file. But an empty one.

Comment: Ok, then that probably means all your feature classes are out of the feature dataset. It would only write out to a csv if it is in a dataset. Put `wr.writerow(fc.split(","))` below `for fc in fcList:` @saravanaganesh18

Comment: As usual. An empty csv

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this, i am unsure why you are trying to split the fc out if its printing fine, maybe the split is causing the issue. This isn't tested, but give it a shot.

```
import arcpy
import csv

dir = r'D:\Test\gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = dir
gdbList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces('*','FileGDB')
filename = r'D:\Test\FC_List.csv'

with open(filename, 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    message = ['featureClass','featureData','gdb']
    wr.writerows([message])

    for gdb in gdbList:
        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        # add [''] to include feature classes outside featureDatasets
        fds = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','feature') + ['']

        for featureData in fds:
            fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',featureData)
            for featureClass in fcs:
                print 'Processing feature class: ' + featureClass   
                message = [featureClass,featureData,gdb]
                wr.writerows([message])
```