# Search if field exists in feature class

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, esri-geodatabase, arccatalog

I have a few dozen feature classes, one of which contains the field I am looking for. They are stored in several different file geodatabases.

Is there a quick way of searching each feature class to find the one that has my field? Or do I have to check each one's attribute table in Catalog? Some of the files have the same names but are stored in separate locations.

I would like to be able to do this inside a `Calculate Value` tool in ModelBuilder, so that each time I needed to, I could run the model on a single file gdb and it would search through all the feature classes within that gdb and look for the field.

So far, I have a feature class iterator which iterates over all the feature classes in the file gdb recursively. Inside the `Calculate Value` I have the following code:

```
findField(r"%Feature%", "%Search Field%")
```

---

```
def findField(fc, fi):
  lst = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
  for f in lst:
    if f.name == fi:
      return fc
    else:
      return "not found"
```

The returned values are collected in `Output Values` as strings. The output for all the feature classes has been "not found", even though the field exists in at least 4 of them. 
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would prefer a list comprehension instead of string operations (like accepted answer). In my opinion, this is more readable and pythonic. Furthermore, the list comprehension approach could be extended by adding further functionality (`str.lower()`, like @RyanDalton did) very easy.

```
def findField(fc, fi):
  fieldnames = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
  if fi in fieldnames:
    return "found in " +fc
  else:
    return "not found in " +fc
```

If you prefer the one liner if-else Statement:

```
def findField(fc, fi):
  fieldnames = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
  return "found in " + fc if fi in fieldnames else "not found in " + fc
```

Or even Shorter, but less readable:

```
    def findField(fc, fi):
      return "found in " + fc if fi in [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)] else "not found in " + fc
```

Answer (score 20):

Check out this function from by Bjorn Kuiper to test if a [field exists](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/04/21/tips-tricks-fieldexists-for-arcgis-10-python/) :

```
def FieldExist(featureclass, fieldname):
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(featureclass, fieldname)

    fieldCount = len(fieldList)

    if (fieldCount == 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

with the following example of use:

```
    if (not FieldExist(myFeatureClass, "myField")):
      arcpy.AddError("Field 'myField' does not exist in " + myFeatureClass)
      sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use ArcPy:

```
import arcpy

myField = "test"

env.workspace = "D:/test/data.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for f in fcs:
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(f)
    for field in fieldList:   
         if field.name == myField:
             print f
```

Beside this you can use os.walk for files in your drive as:

```
path = r"C:"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for fileName in files:
            .........
```

Comment: I have tried with the updated code, it runs but no output even though the field is in several feature classes within the geodatabase.

Answer (score 4):

If your featureclasses are in Feature Datasets, then [@Aragon's solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26898/115) will not work because you need to walk through the feature datasets and then check the featureclasses.

Using [@Aragon's code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26898/115) as well as @gotchula's code from [List all feature classes in GDB, including within feature datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/list-all-feature-classes-in-gdb-including-within-feature-datasets), I produced the following code that will read through all feature datasets and feature classes in a geodatabase.

**NOTE**: By default ListFields appears to be case-sensitive.  I have added code to convert both the user-defined fieldname and the ListField name to lowercase for case-insensitive searches.  You probably would also want to disable most of the print statements, but I left them in there so you can follow the code as it is running.  I also created the sub-function FindField within the so that I could call it multiple times in the script without having to re-code it.

```
import arcpy

def FindField(fc,myField):
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for field in fieldList:
        if str.lower(str(field.name)) == str.lower(myField):
            print "    " + fc + " contains fieldname: " + myField

myField = "test"
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/test/data.gdb"

#Search root level featureclasses
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    print "Searching root level Featureclasses..."
    print "  Searching " + fc
    FindField(fc,myField)

#Search Feature Datasets
for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature'):
    print "Searching FeatureDataset: " + fds

    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
        print "  Searching Featureclass... " + fc
        FindField(fc,myField)
```

Answer (score 3):

A few have danced around the way I would do this, but I just want to add an easy one-line way to do this:

```
if 'fieldname' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
    ## do something.
```

What maybe be more useful (if you are iterating through many feature classes) I would use the opposite of the above as a filter:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    if not 'fieldname' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        continue
    ## now do something with the feature class.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer with some help from the code in the answer to [Using ListFields and CalculateField to find max value in variable number of fields to populate another field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32429). I took all the field names, converted them to a string and then searched the string for my field. The code in the `Calculate Value` now looks as follows:

```
def findField(fc, fi):
  fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
  nameList = []
  for f in fieldList:
    nameList.append(f.name)
  str_lst = "!" + "!, !".join(nameList) + "!"
  return "found in" +fc if str_lst.find(fi) > 0 else "not found in " +fc
```

The `Output Values` now contains the full list of feature classes which has the field I searched for, and `not found` for the rest.

[image: Collect Values output]