# Deleting Service Area Layers using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, network-analyst

Using arcpy I can make a service area layer in Network Analyst like this:

```
outSAResultObject = arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer(inNetworkDataset, outNALayerName,
                              impedanceAttribute, "TRAVEL_FROM", "10",
                              "DETAILED_POLYS", "NO_MERGE",
                              hierarchy = "NO_HIERARCHY")
```

However, where is this created? in "inNetworkDataset" and the GDB associated, but it's not visible in the GDB or ArcMap. It is there somewhere: when I try to run the script again it says

> Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 030036: A layer
>   with this name exists. Failed to execute (MakeServiceAreaLayer).

I change the outNALayerName and it works. I would mainly like to know how to remove or delete old service areas, but am also vaguely curious if it is possible to access them using ArcMap or Catalog

Comment: Not sure where it is stored, but have you tried Delete mang. method to delete it, http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm?

Comment: @artwork21 Thanks for the hint, it works. I should have done a little more experimenting. Question: how did you edit my post? Was I missing something?

Comment: Just some text formatting on your error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've noted in my comment, you may use the [arcpy delete management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm) method to delete the service area layer.

> Permanently deletes data from disk. All types of geographic data
>   supported by ArcGIS, as well as toolboxes and workspaces (folders,
>   geodatabases), can be deleted. If the specified item is a workspace,
>   all contained items are also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
inNetworkDataset = C:\\Temp2\\data.gdb\\Network\\Network_ND
outNALayerName = Catchments

arcpy.Delete_management(r'C:\\Temp2\\data.gdb\\Network\\Network_ND\\Catchments')
```

This deletes it. I wasn't sure if it needed a .lyr, but it seems not. Perhaps there is a way to list the service areas currently in the GDB, as seen in [Listing all feature classes in File Geodatabase, including within feature datasets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase)