# Enabling model tool even if field already exists using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, if-else

I made a quick little tool in ModelBuilder to add specific fields based on a precondition (checked boxes). The issue I'm having is that if any of those fields already exist in the feature I'm trying to add fields too, the tool won't run. Sometimes some of the fields already exist in a feature, and I'm wanting to just add the missing ones. I could delete the existing fields, but then I would lose the data in those fields.

I've found info on a If-Field-Exists logical tool, but I can't seem to find it within ModelBuilder.

Is this a tool found only in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The [If Field Exists](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/if-field-exists.htm) tool is a tool that is in ArcGIS Pro but not available for ArcMap.

If you need to do something similar then a workaround is documented in the ArcMap help as [Using If-Then-Else logic for branching](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm), and it is the subject of at least one Q&A here: [Using Python Script tool in ModelBuilder to check if field exists, if not, create one?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293379)